# CSV reference data in Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I have a stream analytics application where events are JSON encoded and look like this

```
{customerID: 45, state:"S2" , timestamp:"2017-06-06 14:19:21.77"}
{customerID: 74, state:"S2" , timestamp:"2017-06-06 14:19:26.61"}
{customerID: 79, state:"S2" , timestamp:"2017-06-06 14:19:28.50"}
{customerID: 10, state:"D" , timestamp:"2017-06-06 14:19:31.79"}
{customerID: 70, state:"S2" , timestamp:"2017-06-06 14:19:31.93"}
{customerID: 37, state:"S2" , timestamp:"2017-06-06 14:19:32.17"}
{customerID: 41, state:"D" , timestamp:"2017-06-06 14:19:33.48"}
```

I have reference data for customers in a CSV file that looks like this:

```
"CUST_ID", "Age", "Rich"
1, "50", "Y"
2, "22", "N"
```

I load the data files in the aforementioned formats and test the following query

```
select A.[CUSTOMERID], A.[state], B.[AGE], B.[GENDER_CODE] from clickstream A timestamp by A.[TIMESTAMP] left join refdata B on A.[CUSTOMERID]=B.[CUST_ID]
```

I get the following error message with no details:
[image: error]

Now, the same query works perfectly if the data reference data is represented as JSON. Is there a working example I can have a look at with CSV reference data?

Answer (score 1):

> I have reference data for customers in a CSV file

When we [create input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-inputs#create-a-blob-storage-data-stream-input), we need to specify ***Event serialization format*** which let Stream Analytics know which serialization format (JSON, CSV, or Avro) we're using for incoming data streams. Please check the ***Event serialization format*** of your input ***refdata***, and make sure if it is set to CSV.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked that and it is indeed set to CSV. Were you able to successfully test a job with CSV reference data? I cannot even get a minimum working example to test successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with stream analytics.

Just FYI, converting the .csv file to .json file (using a online tool for example), and changing the reference data serialization format to JSON solved the problem. Now I can test the query by submitting the json-file trough the Azure portal query tool.
Seems like CSV implementation of stream analytics is buggy, as I'm sure that my csv was correctly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

"Test" button with reference data didn't work for me at all. I had to use Azure Stream analytics tools for Visual Studio to test it in local environment.

Regarding an error in path pattern. I used `YYYY-MM-DD` and by default stream analytics used `YYYY/MM/DD`. When the job was running, I saw an exclamation mark next to input in Stream analytics dashboard.

[image]

To debug error you should click on reference data input in Stream Analytics overview and you should see warnings on its blade.

Mine warning was like:

`Initializing input without a valid reference data blob for UTC time 11/14/2017 12:22:32 PM, example path: 'https://blabla.blob.core.windows.net/cohorts/2017/11/14/12-22/result.csv'`